# Search a collection based on name

Tags: swift, firebase, uitextfield, full-text-search, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a list of users inside of a collection stored in Firestore.
 /users/uid/{user}

I want to have a UITextField that whenever I search for a letter, it searches the users collection for the results matching that letter.

*example: user types "R" and all R names show up, then "Ry" and it fetches all Ry names then "Ryan" and shows only those names.

Would this have to be done using cloud functions? Or is there a query that you can do with Firestore that will let me achieve that effect.

(For the live search I am simply just going to make a request everytime a letter is typed in to fetch some new data and reload my dataset)